# Gulp unhandled error

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have a pretty simple gulp file with a couple tasks:
- Clean a folder
- Copy files

I have a watch setup. I keep getting an error:

events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/gordon/Dropbox/Dev/MDR/ScribeTab/dist/font/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff'

I don't understand whats wrong, like I said sometimes it works when I run the watch, sometimes it fails on the watch, sometimes it fails when the watch task (default) is ran after I make a change to popup.html.

Here is my complete gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    path = require('path'),
    del = require('del')

    gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'copy'])

    gulp.task('clean', function(){
      return del('dist/**/*');
    });

    gulp.task('copy', function() {

      /* copy fonts */
      var fonts = gulp.src('src/font/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/font"));

      /* copy images */
      var imgs = gulp.src('src/img/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/img"));

      /* copy html files */
      var html = gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));

      /* copy manifest file for google chrome */
      var manifest =  gulp.src('src/manifest.json')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

    });

    // watch
    gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function () {
        gulp.watch(['src/popup.html'], ['default']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something may be running out of order, perhaps try `copy` first then `clean`

Also try adding this error logging function:

```
function errorlog(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    this.emit('end');
}
```

---

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del('dist/**/*')
    .on('error', errorlog);
});
```